# HTML password inputs with placeholder text

Tags: html

How to create input of password type in which value of input is written in text i.e. `Password` but when user clicks on it and type it should be password time i.e. `********`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use placeholder attribute

```
<input type='password' placeholder="password">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need javascript, you can code like this :

```
var p = document.createElement('input');
p.setAttribute('type','Password');
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: **@user3133918**, Thank you for letting me know. If it works for you, You may mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I'd say only use JavaScript if you simply have to insert the element into the DOM at run-time. Otherwise, just use HTML - it's less prone to failure.